# Ícone com contador de notificações

Tags: android

Alguém sabe como eu faço um contador de notificações no Android como o Facebook, whatsapp, segue a foto mostrando o ícone do telefone.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/X02Yl.jpg

Comment: Como ícone acho que não é possível ter essa dinamicidade. Mas sendo um widget que mostre um número posicionado em cima do logo do app é possível. No Widget você monta o layout como quiser, de uma olhada em: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android puro não possui esta funcionalidade, os fabricantes adicionam esta funcionalidade na UI deles e é diferente em cada um deles para se usar este recurso.

No caso do Touchwiz da Samsung seria assim:

```java
public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
    String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
    if (launcherClassName == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Este eu já testei e sei que funciona em um Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, você pode conferir ele no [tópico do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261795) de onde tirei o código, lá tem também um exemplo para dispositivos da Sony, porém nunca cheguei a testar.

Answer (score 1):

Existe essa biblioteca que faz exatamente isto [aqui](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger). O Android não permite que troque o ícone depois que é gerado o APK, basicamente a biblioteca [View Badger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) criar um widget por cima do ícone da aplicação.

Lembrado que a criação de contadores por cima do ícone é considerado como má pratica, segundo a documentação de [design](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) do Android. Notificações são exibidas na barra de notificação.

Comment: Já usei essa biblioteca, bem simples vale a pena dar uma olhada